# Projecting results from a grouping that also need to be summed

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to get my head around a specific problem to decide whether to take the plunge in converting some personal projects to MongoDb after completing a basic course last week. What I am trying to achieve is a representation of my data based on grouping and then ultimately selecting specific parts of that group to create a new projection which shows my final result. In the code presently, we do the grouping and then do a sub-select to create the final dataset, I am hoping this can be done in a single hit.

Example document

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "600d88b0d7016d5675cd59bd"
    },
    "DeviceId": {
        "$oid": "600d729764ea780882ac559b"
    },
    "UserId": {
        "$oid": "600b660eff59aab915985b1d"
    },
    "Date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1611499696095"
        }
    },
    
    "Records": [
        {
             "Count": {
                "$numberInt": "10"
            },
            "Test1": {
                "Inconclusive": null,
                "Passed": true,
                "Failed": null
            },
            "Test2": {
                "Inconclusive": null,
                "Passed": true,
                "Failed": null
            }
           
        },
    {
             "Count": {
                "$numberInt": "15"
            },
            "Test1": {
                "Inconclusive": true,
                "Passed": null,
                "Failed": null
            },
            "Test2": {
                "Inconclusive": null,
                "Passed": true,
                "Failed": null
            }
           
        },
    {
             "Count": {
                "$numberInt": "15"
            },
            "Test1": {
                "Inconclusive": true,
                "Passed": null,
                "Failed": null
            },
            "Test2": {
                "Inconclusive": null,
                "Passed": null,
                "Failed": true
            }
           
        }
    ]
}
```

Ultimately, what I am trying to get is this as close to this as possible;

```
{
    "DeviceId": "600d729764ea780882ac559b",
    "Test1Inconclusive": 30,
    "Test1Passed": 10,
    "Test1Failed": 0,
    "Test2Inconclusive": 0,
    "Test2Passed": 25,
    "Test2Failed": 15
}
```

So far, all I have managed to get is the data grouped and it is at this point in the existing code (Entity Framework/SQL server) that I would use Linq to pull out the SUM'd values.

```
[{
    $match: {
        UserId: ObjectId('600b660eff59aab915985b1d')
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$Records'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            DeviceId: '$DeviceId',
            Test1Inconclusive: '$Records.Test1.Inconclusive',
            Test1Passed: '$Records.Test1.Passed',
            Test1Failed: '$Records.Test1.Failed',
            Test2Inconclusive: '$Records.Test2.Inconclusive',
            Test2Passed: '$Records.Test2.Passed',
            Test2Failed: '$Records.Test2.Failed',
        },
        Count: {
            $sum: '$Records.Count'
        }
    }
}, {}]
```

I am not sure if it is possible to do what I want, and if so how the do the next projection step while performing a subselect of this grouped data. It might even be that my approach is flawed from the start, so feel free to change it completely.

Bonus internet points if you can also give me the MongoDb C# syntax for doing the same (on a MongoCollection)

Comment: the `Records` object having dynamic fields? Test1 and Test2 and Count are dynamic or fixed?

Comment: @turivishal    The number of records is dynamic, the fields are static, it will always have Test1 and Test2 and and overall Count. Thanks

Comment: okay, you need to check condition when sum in $group stage, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uQrvhaS9Nzg), my suggestion is if you want to correct your schema for result fields from `null` to 0 and `true` to 1 so you can save $cond for all calculation in $group stage. see that improvement if you do in your schema [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZsAa_BhZFtR), i wish i could answer but i don't know c#.

Comment: Thanks for getting involved. Unfortunately it doesn’t quite work as the sum is not based on the count, it looks like it’s a sum of the matched conditions. Do you have any idea how it can be refined, it’s very close.

Comment: can you explain more how you want to count? its sum of true condition, if its true then plus 1, means how many true passed test1's count.. so on for other test results

Comment: @turivishal I understand the confusion, the dataset is not great. I solved it by modifying your initial example and using "$Records.Count" rather than 1 in the condition [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kDb5Mb9b4PA)

Comment: okay got it now, you did it. (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the initial version by @turivishal, the answer below worked;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      UserId: ObjectId("600b660eff59aab915985b1d")
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$Records"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$DeviceId",
      Test1Inconclusive: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Records.Test1.Inconclusive",
                true
              ]
            },
            "$Records.Count",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Test1Passed: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Records.Test1.Passed",
                true
              ]
            },
            "$Records.Count",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Test1Failed: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Records.Test1.Failed",
                true
              ]
            },
            "$Records.Count",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Test2Inconclusive: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Records.Test2.Inconclusive",
                true
              ]
            },
            "$Records.Count",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Test2Passed: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Records.Test2.Passed",
                true
              ]
            },
            "$Records.Count",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Test2Failed: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Records.Test2.Failed",
                true
              ]
            },
            "$Records.Count",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Count: {
        $sum: "$Records.Count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```